# On Fermat's Last theorem

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

Fermat's Last theorem states that for $n>2$ there is no solution to the equation $c^n = a^n + b^n$ where $a,b,c$ are positive integers.

Now, let $d_n = \inf_{a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}^*} |c^n - a^n - b^n |$

Do we have any results on the behavior of $d_n$ ?

Thank you for your answer,

Comment: Do you mean the asymptotic behavior of $d_n$ as $n$ grows?

Comment: $d_3=1$: $(9n^4 )^3  - (9n^3  - 1)^3  - (9n^4  - 3n)^3  = 1$. Could be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4019092

Comment: @lhf Yes an asymptotic behavior